# Can gradle build.gradle file support two Artifactories?

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I'm using gradle as a build system. Some dependencies are stored on the first artifactory server, let's call it A1. Everything is setup and works great. However, now the same build.gradle file supposedly needs to support two distinct artifactories - along A1 comes A2.

Is this possible in gradle? Any guides or tips on how to do that?

Sorry if the question is vague - I'll try to narrow the subject if requested, thanks for help.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Can't A1 proxy A2 (define it as a remote repository)?

Comment: A1 is to be disabled, and unfortunately I can't configure A2 *much*. This would be the easier approach for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, just declare another repository:

```
repositories {
    maven {
       url "http://a1/artifactory/lib-releases"
    }
    maven {
       url "http://a2/artifactory/lib-releases"
    }
}
```

But I really suggest proxying A2 in A1, that is exactly what Artifactory does.

Comment: I thought the first way would be better and cleaner, but in fact it is the opposite. In my case I'd like to as transparent as it is possible slowly move files from A1 to A2 (hence at one point in time both artifactories are required). But with the second approach, all I need to do is change A1 conf (add remote repo) - it's already working - then cleanly move all the files from A1 to A2 and lastly, just change the artifactory links. Thanks for *both* suggestions.